# ntfsundelete sh shell script failure

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I am trying to write a script to undelete a lot of files from a windows partition. I was able to pull the inode numbers for all of the files and their names by using the scan function of ntfsundelete.

I then took this huge list and made a file like this:

```
#!/bin/sh  
ntfsundelete /dev/sda2 -u -i 50365 -o file1.doc -d .  
ntfsundelete /dev/sda2 -u -i 58234 -o file1.doc -d .
```

I did chmod +x script.sh and ran it sh ./script.sh

I get the error "Couldn't create output file: No such file or directory".

If I run those commands individually, it works, but if I run the script, it fails. I have 1200+ files.

Comment: `cd c:\path\to\deletedFilesDir` at the top of your script? Good luck.

Comment: assuming the parens around `#` are to avoid bold? Use the `{}` format tool at the top left of the edit box on highlighted text to format as code/data/output. Good luck.

Comment: and, for my information and learning, what OS has `ntfsundelete `?

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the formatting, you were correct. ntfsundelete is a linux command for retrieving deleted files from a windows partition.

Comment: biit forcing the script to `cd` to dir with deleted files didn't help? I recenttly saw an article about how the Windows Undelete process works. It keeps a separate "database" of deleted files and their original locations. If `cd` didn't help, you'll need to research what is the correct usage of `ntfsdelete`. AND of course,  you don't want to be writing any new files to that disk . That's all I can offer for help. Good luck.!

Comment: doah, and of course, my original comment should have been `cd /path/to/deletedFiles` at the top of your script?. Good luck!